# Entity Framework 4: Generic Repository: How do I determine the EntitySetName?

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-4

If you do a generic repository for an Entity in Entity Framework 4, you would start by querying the entity:

```
public IEnumerable<E> GetEntity()
{
    return _container.CreateQuery<E>( ... );
}
```

in that `...` above we need the EntitySetName, which is usually the plural form of `E`'s name.  However, it's not always just as easy as adding an 's'.  For example, this would work if we only just added an 's'.

```
    return _container.CreateQuery<E>( "[" + typeof(E).Name + "s]");
```

This would contain our EntitySetName if we had a real entity:

```
E.EntityKey.EntitySetName
```

How can I get the EntitySetName when only provided the Type of E?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's tricky, especially when proxies are involved, but possible. Here's how I do it in [Halfpipe](http://halfpipe.codeplex.com/):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns entity set name for a given entity type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">An ObjectContext which defines the entity set for entityType. Must be non-null.</param>
    /// <param name="entityType">An entity type. Must be non-null and have an entity set defined in the context argument.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">If entityType is not an entity or has no entity set defined in context.</exception>
    /// <returns>String name of the entity set.</returns>
    internal static string GetEntitySetName(this ObjectContext context, Type entityType)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        if (entityType == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entityType");
        }
        // when POCO proxies are enabled, "entityType" may be a subtype of the mapped type.
        Type nonProxyEntityType = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entityType);
        if (entityType == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,
                Halfpipe.Resource.TypeIsNotAnEntity,
                entityType.Name));
        }

        var container = context.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(context.DefaultContainerName, System.Data.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace.CSpace);
        var result = (from entitySet in container.BaseEntitySets
                      where entitySet.ElementType.Name.Equals(nonProxyEntityType.Name)
                      select entitySet.Name).SingleOrDefault();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,
                Halfpipe.Resource.TypeIsNotAnEntity,
                entityType.Name));
        }
        return result;
    }
```